# Different DNS Server on Different Wifi Networks

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, dns, windows-10

Is there a way for me to use Google DNS Server on my home network, but have automatic DNS server selection on my school's wifi?  They have an in browser authentication which doesn't work with static DNS servers.

I am using a Windows 10 laptop.

Comment: Configure the DNS servers in your home router.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot I could change it from there  @DavidPostill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two options:

1.Configure your home router to use google dns.

2.when in school's wifi,configure windows to obtain dns automatically.Then when you are home,use google dns.

http://www.howtogeek.com/164981/how-to-switch-to-opendns-or-google-dns-to-speed-up-web-browsing/